# Round down a number to 1 decimal place

Tags: python, rounding

I want to get my result of a formula to be 1 decimal place but rounded down.
Is there a formula I could add to print?
Is there a trim perhaps? That could also work.

Answer (score 8):

```
from math import floor
x = 8.64
x = floor(x*10)/10
print(x)
```

8.6

Comment: *"I want to get my result of a formula to be **1 decimal place** but rounded down"*

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use a round function

```
x = round(5.76543, 2)
print(x)
```

This will return `x = 5.77` . I think that's what you wanted.

Comment: I neec it to round down, round alone will round UP

Comment: Why don't you add some example to let us understand what you actually want. Try out what others OP suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import math
num = 3.678
rounded_num = math.floor(num*10)/10
print(rounded_num) # output: 3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply multiply by 10 and apply the `math.ceil` function

```
import math
def one_decimal(n):
  return math.ceil(n*10)/10.0
```